# Sending and receiving push notifications via AWS SNS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I've been trying to to create an app in order to send and receive push notifications via AWS SNS. I am new to the API and couldn't find a reliable tutorial. Here is the functions I've came up with in order to send and receive notifications:

```
func subscribe(deviceTokenString : String)
{
    let credentialsProvider : AWSStaticCredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: AWSAccessKey, secretKey: AWSSecretKey)
    let defaultServiceConfiguration : AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration

    let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()

    let subscribeInput = AWSSNSSubscribeInput()

    subscribeInput.topicArn = SNSTopicARN

    sns.subscribe(subscribeInput).continueWithBlock
    {
        (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if task.error != nil
        {
            print("Subscribed successfully")
            let confirmSubscription = AWSSNSConfirmSubscriptionInput()
            confirmSubscription.topicArn = SNSTopicARN
            confirmSubscription.token = deviceTokenString
            sns.confirmSubscription(confirmSubscription).continueWithBlock
            {
                (task) -> AnyObject! in
                if task.error != nil
                {
                    print("Confirmed subscription")
                    self.sendMessage()
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Subscription confirmation failed with error: \(task.error)")
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error while subscribing: \(task.error)")
        }
        return nil
    }

}

func sendMessage()
{
    let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
    let request = AWSSNSPublishInput()
    request.messageStructure = "json"

    let dict = ["default": "Hello World!", "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"HELLO WORLD!\",\"sound\":\"default\", \"badge\":\"1\"} }"]

    do
    {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        request.message = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        request.topicArn = SNSTopicARN
        sns.publish(request).continueWithBlock
        {
            (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil
            {
                print("Error sending mesage: \(task.error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Success sending message")
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error on json serialization: \(error)")
    }

}
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    let deviceTokenString = "\(deviceToken)"
        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"<>"))
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    print("deviceTokenString: \(deviceTokenString)")
    subscribe(deviceTokenString)
}
```

Everything seems to work well, I get the "Subscribed successfully", "Confirmed subscription" and "Message sent" logs on the console, but `application:didReceiveRemoteNotificationuserInfo:` never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am surprised that the `subscribe` call succeeded since `protocols` is missing (it is [required](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSNSSubscribeInput.html) according to the API reference). You should try out [SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Swift) to see how you can integrate Amazon SNS Mobile Push in your app. As a separate note, you should not embed your AWS credentials in your app. Also, in general you should publish push notifications from your servers in order to avoid spams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured out that I was missing some points. Here is the piece of code perfectly works.

```
func subscribe(token : String, completionHandler : ((NSError?) -> ())? = nil)
{
    let credentialsProvider : AWSStaticCredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: AWSAccessKeySend, secretKey: AWSSecretKeySend)
    let defaultServiceConfiguration : AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration

    let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
    let createPlatformEndpointInput = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
    createPlatformEndpointInput.token = token
    createPlatformEndpointInput.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn

    sns.createPlatformEndpoint(createPlatformEndpointInput).continueWithBlock
    {
        (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if task.error != nil
        {
            print("Error creating platform endpoint: \(task.error)")
            completionHandler?(task.error)
            return nil
        }
        let result = task.result as! AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
        let subscribeInput = AWSSNSSubscribeInput()
        subscribeInput.topicArn = SNSTopicARN
        subscribeInput.endpoint = result.endpointArn
        print("Endpoint arn: \(result.endpointArn)")
        subscribeInput.protocols = "application"
        sns.subscribe(subscribeInput).continueWithBlock
        {
            (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil
            {
                completionHandler?(task.error)
                print("Error subscribing: \(task.error)")
                return nil
            }
            print("Subscribed succesfully")
            let subscriptionConfirmInput = AWSSNSConfirmSubscriptionInput()
            subscriptionConfirmInput.token = token
            subscriptionConfirmInput.topicArn = SNSTopicARN
            sns.confirmSubscription(subscriptionConfirmInput).continueWithBlock
            {
                (task) -> AnyObject! in
                if task.error != nil
                {
                    print("Confirmed subscription")
                }
                completionHandler?(task.error)
                return nil
            }
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }
}

func sendMessage(message : String, type : String = "alert", sound : String = "default", badges : Int = 1, completionHandler : ((NSError?) -> ())? = nil)
{
    let credentialsProvider : AWSStaticCredentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: AWSAccessKeySend, secretKey: AWSSecretKeySend)
    let defaultServiceConfiguration : AWSServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: DefaultServiceRegionType, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration


    let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
    let request = AWSSNSPublishInput()
    request.messageStructure = "json"

    let dict = ["default": message, "APNS_SANDBOX": "{\"aps\":{\"\(type)\": \"\(message)\",\"sound\":\"\(sound)\", \"badge\":\"\(badges)\"} }"]

    do
    {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        request.message = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        request.topicArn = SNSTopicARN

        sns.publish(request).continueWithBlock
        {
            (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil
            {
                print("Error sending mesage: \(task.error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Success sending message")
            }
            completionHandler?(task.error)
            return nil
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error on json serialization: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is old but still this is the only piece of code I could find to be able to send notifications via Swift. Some changes were needed for newer Swift version.